# Could not find FeatureManager when running test on REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, illegalstateexception, togglz

I get this error when trying to run a test:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find the FeatureManager. For web applications please verify that the TogglzFilter starts up correctly. In other deployment scenarios you will typically have to implement a FeatureManagerProvider as described in the 'Advanced Configuration' chapter of the documentation.
>
> at org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext.getFeatureManager(FeatureContext.java:52)
> at ie.aviva.digital.pricegenerator.config.FeatureOptions.isActive(FeatureOptions.java:14)
> at ie.aviva.digital.pricegenerator.controller.mta.MtaController.quoteForTempAdditionalDriver(MtaController.java:79)
> at ie.aviva.digital.pricegenerator.controller.mta.MtaControllerTest.temp_add_driver_controller_behaviour_test(MtaControllerTest.java:166)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:55)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:100)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:107)
> at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:41)
> at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
> at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

Anything I can find on this talks about adding something like this wo web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>TogglzFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.togglz.servlet.TogglzFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>TogglzFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm working on a REST API so don't have a web.xml. I'm using `Spring Boot` 2.6.2 and `Togglz` version 3.2.1.

This is my `Togglz` configuriation:

```
@Configuration
public class TogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {

  public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
    return FeatureOptions.class;
  }

  @Override
  public StateRepository getStateRepository() {
    return new InMemoryStateRepository();
  }

  @Override
  public UserProvider getUserProvider() {
    return new SpringSecurityUserProvider("admin");
  }
}
```

Here's my featureOptions:

```
public enum FeatureOptions implements Feature {
  @Label("Temporary driver")
  TEMP_DRIVER;

  public boolean isActive() {
    return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
  }
}
```

MyController:

```
public class MyController {

  private FeatureManager featureManager;

  public MyController(FeatureManager featureManager) {
    this.featureManager = featureManager;
  }

  ...

  public ResponseEntity<MyResponse> tempDriver(@RequestBody
          MyTempDriverRequest request) {
    if (FeatureOptions.TEMP_DRIVER.isActive()) {
      if (request
          .getTempDriver()
          .equals("")) {
        request.getTempDriver().setCountry("GB");
      }
    }
    ...
}
```

My application.properties is:

```
togglz.console.enabled=false
togglz.console.secured=false
togglz.features.TEMP_DRIVER.enabled=true
togglz.console.use-management-port=false
```

One thing I do notice when I run the application v's my test is that in the application, my debugger show's the featureManager like this:
[image]

In the test, the debugger shows it like this:

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: There is far too little information here, my initial reaction would be read the documentation that is referenced in the error message. I suspect you are using Spring Boot 3 with togglez configured for web which isn't supporting JakartaEE yet and thus doesn't work. But without versions and your configuration this will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added some more info but will also take another look at the documentation.